# Source of the story Mrigari - The Hunter and Narada?

Tags: identification-request, skanda-purana

The story of Mrigari - The Hunter transformed by association of Narada muni is briefly recollected in [Chaitanya Charitamrita, madhya lila, 24th chapter](https://www.vedabase.com/en/cc/madhya/24/) from verse 229.

I found it in [Stories from the Skanda Purana](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/8187812761)

[image]

Can someone point the exact location in Skanda Purana?